# How to re-render another component after setState in ReactTable getTdProps onClick event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, render, react-table

I have two react-table tables on a page.  The first shows a list of saved queries.  A user can click on any of the saved queries to run the query results, which are rendered in a second table.  I'm trying to show / hide the query results table based on the boolean state of "showQueryResults".

When I setState of showQueryResults to false from within the getTDProps onClick event handler, nothing happens.  When I put a test button elsewhere on the page which does the exact same thing, the query results table is successfully hidden.

```
<ReactTable
    data={this.props.data}
    columns={columns}
    getTdProps={(state, rowInfo, column) => {
      return {
        onClick: () => {
          if (rowInfo){
            const row = rowInfo.row
            this.setState({selectedListId: row.id, showQueryResults: false},() => {
                if(column.id !== 'delete'){
                  if (row.search_type === 'dynamic'){
                    this.props.fetchQueryResults(row._original.search_criteria)
                      .then(this.setState({showQueryResults: true}))
                  } else {
                    this.props.fetchStaticResults(row.id)
                      .then(this.setState({showQueryResults: true}))
                  }
                }
              });
          }
        },
    }}}
/>
```

In my main render function, I'm conditionally rendering the query results as follows:

```
{
 this.state.showQueryResults
 ? <ListResults
   queryResults = {this.props.queryResults}
   onModalToggle = {this.handleModalToggle.bind(this)}
   showSave = {false}
   />
   : null
 }
```

And like I said, the following test button successfully hides the above element:

```
<button onClick={() => this.setState({showQueryResults: !this.state.showQueryResults})}>Toggle</button>
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT: I've also tried the following to try to make sure the fetchQueryResults completes before the second setState (per the comments) but this is doing the exact same thing:

```
      <ReactTable
    data={this.props.data}
    columns={columns}
    getTdProps={(state, rowInfo, column) => {
      return {
        onClick: () => {
          if (rowInfo){

            const row = rowInfo.row

            const handleFetchQuery = (searchCriteria) => {
              return new Promise((resolve)=>{
                let response = this.props.fetchQueryResults(searchCriteria)
                if (response){
                  resolve('Success')
                }

              })
            }

            this.setState({selectedListId: row.id, showQueryResults: false},() => {
                if(column.id !== 'delete'){
                  if (row.search_type === 'dynamic'){
                    handleFetchQuery(row._original.search_criteria)
                      .then(() => {this.setState({showQueryResults: true})})
                  } else {
                    this.props.fetchStaticResults(row.id)
                      .then(this.setState({showQueryResults: true}))
                  }
                }
              });
          }
        },
    }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

After this `setState`

```
this.setState({selectedListId: row.id, showQueryResults: false}
```

you trigger another `setState` in the callback

```
if(column.id !== 'delete'){
  if (row.search_type === 'dynamic'){
     this.props.fetchQueryResults(row._original.search_criteria)
       .then(this.setState({showQueryResults: true}))
  } else {
     this.props.fetchStaticResults(row.id)
      .then(this.setState({showQueryResults: true}))
  }
}
```

so the `showQueryResults` is `true`, then your condition in

```
{
 this.state.showQueryResults
  ? <ListResults
    queryResults = {this.props.queryResults}
    onModalToggle = {this.handleModalToggle.bind(this)}
    showSave = {false}
   />
   : null
}
```

will always render the true condition. Meaning your table will always be visible.

Comment: So I'm trying to hide the component  with `setState({showQueryResults: false})`, then fetch new results, and the show the component with the new results with `setState({showQueryResults: true})`.   From what I can tell, I'm fetching the new results in the original setState callback, and then waiting for the fetch to finish before resetting state.  It takes some time for the results to come back, and in the meantime the original results are never hidden.

Comment: The more I look at this, I do think the problem is with the second setState happening too quickly after the first setState, but I don't understand why the setState is happening before the fetchQueryResults is complete.  Editing my original response to show the other way I've tried this.

Answer (score 0):

So I've gotten this to work in the following way using async/await:

```
      <ReactTable
      data={this.props.data}
      columns={columns}
      getTdProps={(state, rowInfo, column) => {
          return {
            onClick: () => {
              if (rowInfo){

                const row = rowInfo.row

                const handleFetchQuery = async (searchCriteria) => {
                   await this.props.fetchQueryResults(searchCriteria)
                   .then(success => {this.setState({showQueryResults: !this.state.showQueryResults})
                })}

                const handleFetchStatic = async (listId) => {
                   await this.props.fetchStaticResults(listId)
                   .then(success => {this.setState({showQueryResults: !this.state.showQueryResults})
                })}

                this.setState({selectedListId: row.id, showQueryResults: false},() => {
                if(column.id !== 'delete'){
                  if (row.search_type === 'dynamic'){
                      try {
                        handleFetchQuery(row._original.search_criteria)
                      } catch (e) {
                        console.log(e)
                      }

                  } else {
                      try {
                        handleFetchStatic(row.id)
                      } catch (e) {
                        console.log(e)
                      }
                }
              }
              });
          }
        },
    }}}
  />
```

Still not sure why it wasn't working the previous ways, but I'll take it!  And hopefully this helps someone else in the future.